# SQL Prepared Statement Error on my Search form

Tags: php, sql, sql-injection

I am finding it difficult to write a SQL prepared statement for my search form, can I get help on fixing it? Everything works great without a SQL prepared  bind statement but am sure it's not so secure.

Here is my CODE:

```
<?php
  // Define Database connection parameters 
  $dbserver = "localhost";
  $username = "root";
  $password = "";
  $dbname = "student";
  // Lets Connect to theDatabase Table, But if there is an Error lets tell before its too late to figured
  $conn = mysqli_connect ( $dbserver, $username, $password, $dbname ) or die ( ' I can not connect to the database ' );

   // Its time to Capture the varibles and user inpute from the form , also we need to sanitize the input to avoid SQL Injection    
  $study_group = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $conn, $_POST['matric_number']);

  /* Lets try to use bind Statement to reduce further hacking

  I am also avoiding using "LIKE" Clause because IVariable direct Exact results so will be using the Direct Varible 
  */

  $sql = $conn->prepare (" SELECT * FROM study_circle WHERE matric = ? ") ;
  $sql->bind_param('s', $study_group);
  $sql ->execute();

  $results = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);
  $mysqlResults = mysqli_num_rows ($results);

  if (  $mysqlResults > 0   )
  { 
    while (  $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ( $results )) 
    {
      // Display results in table form
      echo " <div>
        <h4> ".$row['full_name']."</h4>
      </div>";
     }      
  } else {
    echo " Please Ensure your Matric Number is correct, We can not find anything relting to your data";
  }
```

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: You should not escape your values when you use a prepared statement, now it will check for a litteraly quoted value.

Comment: `$results = mysqli_query ($conn, $sql);`. At this point, `$sql` is a statement object, not a string containing a SQL query. The row is pretty useless as well since you've already made the query a few lines before.

Answer (score 1):

if you use prepared  statement  you should not  use mysqli_real_escape_string

Try comment  the mysqli_real_escape_string row and use   $_POST['matric_number'] directly in bind_param

```
// $study_group = mysqli_real_escape_string ( $conn, $_POST['matric_number']);

/* Lets try to use bind Statement to reduce further hacking
```

I am also avoiding using "LIKE" Clause because IVariable direct Exact results so will be using the Direct Varible 
*/

```
$sql = $conn->prepare (" SELECT * FROM study_circle WHERE matric = ? ") ;
$sql->bind_param('s',  $_POST['matric_number']);
$sql ->execute();
```

The binding param and prepared  statement prevents SQL injection so you don't need  mysqli_real_escape_string  operation